# Is there a way to "deprecate" a library method in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

We have a third-party library method which is overloaded to accept one or more arguments. We found that using the single parameter variation is problematic and want IntelliJ to warn the user when that variation is being used. Does anyone know how to set up this code inspection rule?

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Structural Search Inspection*. You can copy the *existing method* calls templates and modify it for your needs. This way you get a warning in the editor the moment the unwanted method call it written.